# ES6 Map, showing exception intermittently , Uncaught TypeError: map.put is not a function

Tags: javascript, es6-map

Few weeks back map.put used to work, but now we get this error message intermittently :

```
var mapTypeSubtype = new Map();
Uncaught TypeError: mapTypeSubtype.put is not a function
    at Test.js:411
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at objGenericListener (Test.js:410)
```

Is this an issue from Javascript api side? I saw the documentation and there is no method like `.put` ,  it has been changed to `.set`. But the strange thing is put used to work without any issues, but now its intermittently working. Any suggestions? To change it to `.set` it will be a big change for us as we have used maps in many places in our project.

**Update**

After doing a lot of search from where the put method is introduced, I saw that there is a js which gets loaded in browser which is internal to `salesforce`. And this was defined in that.

```
Map.prototype.put = function(a, b) {
    a && "undefined" != typeof b && (a in this.map || this.size++,
    this.map[a] = b)
}
```

So i think this might not be loaded sometimes which is breaking our implementation.

Thanks

Comment: There was never a `.put` method in `Map.prototype`. Did you have a custom `Map.prototype.put` before?

Comment: No, we always had this declared : `var mapTypeSubtype = new Map();`

Comment: How was that possibly working? This post was asked in 2010, back in then also there was no put method! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966947/dynamically-add-data-to-a-javascript-map

Comment: Map never had put. Check here https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-constructor. Official documentation. You sure no body added custom put in Map prototype?

Comment: Yes I am sure, even now it works sometimes.

Comment: Do this: `console.log(String(Map.prototype.put));` If that ever prints something besides `undefined`, take that string and search your codebase to find where it's implemented, and _delete it_. Then use `set()` instead. FYI, refactoring all occurrences of `.put()` in a codebase should be very simple with a sufficiently advanced IDE such as Notepad++, Sublime Text, VSCode, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you knew that **there is not any `put` method in the `Map` class**, as the @Mahendra Pratap mentioned on 
 `ES6` document (https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-constructor).

You can run something like below script before using `Map` to prevent refactoring your project:

```
Map.prototype.put = function(key, value){
    return this.set(key, value);
}
```

> More details

Some Guesses of Why your code working:

- Maybe there is `Map.prototype.put` somewhere on your project or in the included libraries.
- There is `put` method in the `HashMap` class in the `java` not in the `javascript`. Make sure you are using `javascript`.
- You can find some implementation of `HashMap` in javascript here: [JavaScript Hashmap Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368280/javascript-hashmap-equivalent)